# Different font size inside textfield IOS 10

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, xcode8, ios10

I am testing my application in the new IOS 10, with Xcode-beta 8.
I have no idea why, but one of my text fields is displaying just the first letter in the right size.

[image: Input image]

It was working fine in the older versions.

Comment: Without any code how can we possibly be expected to help with this? Also, given that this is beta 1 it's very possible that it may be a bug.

Comment: Sorry for the poor information. I've solved the problem. My input has font-size 12, but for some reason the xcode changed the 'min font size' to 17.

Comment: Ah :D well glad you managed to fix it :)